# Pandas: groupby and merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge, append, apply

I have this dataframe in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        "G": ["F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"],
        "BG": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "Zus": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    }
)
```

with this Output:

```
Out[45]: 
     A  G  BG Zus
0   19  F   1   A
1   19  F   1   B
2   19  F   1   C
3   19  F   1   D
4   19  F   1   E
5   19  F   1   F
6   20  F   2   A
7   20  F   2   B
8   20  F   2   C
9   20  F   2   D
10  20  F   2   E
11  20  F   2   F
```

and I have this list:
`ZR = list([0,1,2,3,4])`

What I want to have is a DataFrame like this:

```
A  G  BG Zus  ZR
19  F   1   A  0
19  F   1   B  0
19  F   1   C  0
19  F   1   D  0
19  F   1   E  0
19  F   1   F  0
19  F   1   A  1
19  F   1   B  1
19  F   1   C  1
19  F   1   D  1
19  F   1   E  1
19  F   1   F  1
....
19  F   1   A  4
19  F   1   B  4
19  F   1   C  4
19  F   1   D  4
19  F   1   E  4
19  F   1   F  4
20  F   2   A  0
20  F   2   B  0
20  F   2   C  0
20  F   2   D  0
20  F   2   E  0
20  F   2   F  0
...
20  F   2   A  4
20  F   2   B  4
20  F   2   C  4
20  F   2   D  4
20  F   2   E  4
20  F   2   F  4
```

Can someone help me please? I tried with groupby, apply, append, assign, but nothing worked as I wanted...I hope someone could help

Comment: Show your attempt closest to solving the problem

Comment: Ir order important?

Comment: order is important, I deleted my tries...

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it similarly to a dictionary.

```py
data_frame[column_name] = column_list
```

in you case:

```py
test["ZR"] = ZR
```

Comment: sorry, I edited a few seconds ago :(